# How to interpret "failed to VM allocate" from Guard Malloc in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Is there a good tutorial on interpretation and problem-solving with Guard Malloc?

I'm getting message like "Failed to VM allocate 262144 bytes", and I have no idea what this means. Initially I thought it was the lack of RAM in the system, but maybe not so. If it is a problem I desperately need to learn how to interpret and catch the error.

Another question I have with Guard Malloc is whether it guards memory allocated in C codes of the project (it should right? considering the name) or only applying only to Objective-C? The reason I asked is that I just found out NSZombieEnabled only applies to Obj-C.

Help very much appreciated. I've been messing with likely memory errors for days. And I've not been able to compile Valgrind for iOS yet.

Comment: I cannot even get guard malloc to work!  How did you manage it?

Comment: Really? It was just as easy as checking a check box for me. It is under Product->Edit scheme->diagnostics. I also have four environmental variables set. But I don't know if any of these has to do with it. The four are NSZombieEnabled, NSAutoreleaseFreedObjectCheckEnabled, NSDebugEnabled, and MallocStackLogging.

Comment: When I run my program with that set I get "cannot find dyld /usr/lib/libgmalloc.dyld" (or something similar).  I thought it was recognised as broken under Xcode 4...

Comment: Where did you get that message? As soon as it is ran? I checked again and I cannot find anything regarding any dyld. Again I get these messages:
GuardMalloc[OfflineSpotty-5607]: Failed to VM allocate 262144 bytes
GuardMalloc[OfflineSpotty-5607]: Explicitly trapping into debugger!!!

Comment: It was as reported here: http://osdir.com/ml/xcode-users/2012-04/msg00091.html

Comment: Is that why I find so little information on how to use this, because it doesn't work for most people. I have no luck running Valgrind. I compiled it but it will crash as soon as I start it.

Comment: I do have /usr/lib/libgmalloc.dylib which points to libgmalloc.B.dylib

Comment: Yeah I don't have it on mine... (10.7.4).

Comment: 10.7.4 for me, too. A new version of Xcode is release (today?) I wonder if it would help. =/ Either way, I guess Guard Malloc is not very often used by people. What I am also really afraid other than reusing the freed c pointer is also buffer overruns. What's the best option I have in checking the errors?

Comment: Just run it inside `Instruments` and give it a good work out.

Comment: Guard malloc works well for me, but not on an iOS device, only in the iOS simulator (and the documentation confirms that)

Answer (score 5):

1) I've been chalking up allocation failures with guard malloc on to address space exhaustion -- every allocation takes up at least a page of address space that can't be reused. Uses of memory that is not currently allocated will crash in guard malloc, not cause allocation failures.

2) as the name suggests, guard malloc replaces the implementation of malloc(3), so C code that uses malloc will be checked.

Note that guard malloc is not a silver bullet. You still have to expose your app's bugs through testing; guard malloc just causes crashes to happen earlier and more reliably.

You might also want to read "man libgmalloc".

Answer (score 2):

I was seeing this running on the ios simulator with Guard Malloc set. Choosing the 64-bit device for the simulator stopped the error coming up.

Comment: This worked for me - I was debugging using a 32 bit simulator and crashing out after around 2GB of allocations. Switching to a 64 bit simulator fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

"Failed to VM allocate" is lack of available RAM, as you suspected.

I can only reliably use Guard Malloc when I close every other program on my mac, and even then it sometimes fails with greedy programs that use a lot of memory.

You'll need to:

1. Buy more RAM
2. Close all other running programs on your mac
3. Reduce the memory used by your program through profiling/optimization.

Comment: I got "Failed to VM allocate 524304 bytes" while Activity Monitor says that there is 1.9 GB of free system memory, so I don't think it's quite as simple as lack of RAM.  Maybe address space exhaustion, since I'm debugging a 32-bit process.